# How to get class instance that is lib.jar from web-app.war under jetty?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I have two maven modules. First module contains utility class and works with DB, properties files and also starts embedded jetty server. After build it is represented by lib.jar.

Second module is web-app (some web UI forms) and it uses (at least I want to use) utility class from the first module for filling web form with data.

Embedded jetty server runs web-app.war that is built in the second module.

The result folder structure (jetty uses it) is the following:

```
webapp
|/bin [script to launch jetty -> it calls jetty launch methods from lib.jar]
|/data [data (config, properties files) that is read out by classes from lib.jar]
|/libs [lib.jar and other libs are here]
|/web [web-app.war is here]
```

What I want to do, is to get access to utility class in lib.jar from web-app.war using the folder structure above and get data via public interface in it. Is there any way to do it?

I'll reformulate question if it is still vague.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working embedded, you should have an instance of a WebAppContext on which you can alter the classpath settings with setExtraClassPath()...or simply setParentLoaderPriority() to true should work as well.  Method names may be a bit off, code is not in front of me.

Comment: Yeah, you hit the target - setExtraClassPath() is what I really needed :) Thanks a lot for quick answer.